# proguard configuration with groundy Tasks

Tags: android, annotations, proguard, groundy

I'm using the android "Groundy" library containing the GroundTask class, which makes use of annotations. Further I created a class

```
public class DownloadTask extends GroundyTask
```

and a callback object:

```
  private final Object mCallback = new Object() {
    @OnProgress(DownloadTask.class)
    public void onNiceProgress(@Param(Groundy.PROGRESS) int progress) {
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress);
    }
....
```

But after obfusecation using proguard the method annotated with "OnProgress" never gets called (but no errors occure)

In the proguard file I added

```
-keep class com.telly.groundy.*** {
public protected private *;
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes *OnSuccess*
-keepattributes *OnProgress*
-keepattributes *OnCancel*
-keepattributes *OnCallback*
-keepattributes *OnFailure*
-keepattributes *OnStart*
-keepattributes *Param*
-keepattributes *Traverse*

-keep class com.my.namespace.DownloadTask {
 public protected private *;
}
```

Any idea what "keep" configurations could be missing here ?

Comment: Hello @fritz i am got same problem. are you getting answer?

Comment: No, I decided not to use it any more.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a basic proguard configuration to the readme. It looks like this:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @com.telly.groundy.annotations.* *;
    <init>();
}

-keepnames class com.telly.groundy.generated.*
-keep class com.telly.groundy.generated.*
-keep class com.telly.groundy.ResultProxy
-keepnames class * extends com.telly.groundy.ResultProxy
-keep class * extends com.telly.groundy.GroundyTask
```

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard doesn't know that the code accesses the annotation through reflection, so you probably need to preserve it explicitly:

```
-keep @interface com.telly.groundy.annotations.OnProgress
```